# CSS mask part of div to show div underneath?

Tags: css, overlay, transparency

I am trying to build a "help" overlay in which most of the page is covered by a transparent overlay except that certain areas have circles over them in which the page shows through.  For example, I could create the following div as my overlay, and then position a circular div around the area in question - but what can I do so that the content from below the overlay shows through? (To my knowledge, there's no combination of z-index or transparency that can achieve this)

```
 .overlay {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Kicking this away as off-topic is really sad. The main reason i see for that is that, unfortunately, there is no easy solution for something that could (and should) have one. A simple option allowing a div to be filled out of its border instead of inside could exist, and you don't know such an option does not exist until ... you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Question is a little unspecific. Hard to understand what is your problem.

Maybe you are searching for something like this?

`fiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/7CPbY/4/

Edit:

You could try to create four divs with the same background-color around your area. The fifth div (above the area) could be an image with the same color and a transparent circle in middle.

```
----------------
|     div      |
----------------
|div| area |div|
----------------
|     div      |
----------------
```

Comment: Thanks, but not quite what I'm looking for... I need to figure out a better way to word this, apparently.  I basically want to make a circular div that doesn't receive the "overlay" background, so you can see the page content underneath it w/out the grey on top. Essentially like masking an image.  I suspect this is not possible in CSS, at least, not directly - I was hoping there might be a sneaky workaround.

Comment: Thank you! The div solution looks promising - will test it out!